# nested if in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller

i have controller with nested if to show different view if condition occur my problem it show me first view (view_admin) if condition happen only the first condition otherwise if any  conditions  like "accountant" or "support" occurs it give me last else view (view-ask) any help

code:

```
   if($user_info->privilege == "admin"){
    $this->load->view('dash/view_admin',$data);
    
    }
    else if($user_info->privilege == "accountant"){

    $this->load->view('dash/view_accountant',$data);
    
    }
    else if($user_info->privilege = "support"){

    $this->load->view('dash/view_support',$data);
    }
    
    else {

    $this->load->view('dash/view-ask',$data);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping `$user_info->privilege` to see what it actually contains in cases that provide incorrect view? Also, just for educational purposes, that's not a nested if. A nested if means you have an if inside another if, not a chain of if-elseif statements.

Comment: yes. it's fine it gives the right value

Comment: I've just noticed you have `$user_info->privilege = "support"`, you're reassigning the value there instead of comparing.

Comment: Also, are you absolutely sure the value is the same? `"Accountant"` will not match `"accountant"`.

Comment: @El_Vanja yes you are right.

Comment: @Nada show us your database table please.

Answer (score 0):

In your 3rd condition you are missing **"="**

```
else if($user_info->privilege = "support"){

    $this->load->view('dash/view_support',$data);
    }
```

make this

```
 else if($user_info->privilege == "support"){

    $this->load->view('dash/view_support',$data);
    }
```

try this.

if the problem is not solved `var_dump($user_info->privilege);` and add output to question

Goodluck